# How to compute this character?

Tags: representation-theory, characters

Let $K$ a field of characteristic $0$ and $K[G]$ a group algebra of a finite group $G$.
Let $I$ be a left ideal of $K[G]$ generated by an idempotent $e$ and $\rho: G \longrightarrow GL(I)$ a representation defined by $\rho(g)(ae)=gae$.
Does someone know how to compute $\chi_{\rho}$ ?
Many thanks in advance !

Comment: If $I^2 \neq \{0\}$ then there exists a non-zero idempotent $e \in I$ such that $I=K[G]e$.

Answer (score 1):

For each $g \in G$, the value $\chi(g)$ is the trace of the composed map
$$ I \to K[G] \stackrel{g\cdot }{\to} K[G] \stackrel{\cdot e}{\to} I, $$
where the first map is the inclusion map. By the usual trace properties, it can also be computed as the trace of the composed map
$$ K[G] \stackrel{\cdot e}{\to} I \to K[G] \stackrel{g\cdot }{\to} K[G]. $$
Now we may use the standard basis $G$ of $K[G]$. For each $h \in G$ and $x \in K[G]$ let $\langle x , h \rangle \in K$ denote the coefficient of $h$ in $x$ (which of course may also be represented by a formula such as $\langle x , h \rangle = \rho(xh^{-1}) / |G|$, where $\rho$ is the regular character of $G$). With that notation, we have
$$ \chi(g) = \sum_{h \in G} \langle ghe, h \rangle. $$

Comment: I guess it depends on the application you have in mind whether this answer is useful or not...

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know if I had to consider the representation $\rho$ like an irreducible one.

Comment: Dune: you meant $\chi(xh^{-1})/|G|$ (not $\rho$...) right ?

Comment: @beginarray: No, I actually meant $\rho$ being the character of the [regular representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_representation) of $G$ (aka the regular character), which is a quite common notation. But of course you already used that symbol for a representation. Sorry for causing confusion...